# PHP: Convert "squiggles and hooks" text to normal english/latin alphabet letters

Tags: php, decode

There are some "squiggles and hooks" text generators what can convert normal latin letters into playful text style.

[image]

What I want to do is can decode/covert these style of texts into normal latin letters.

for example:

**Input:** Here are some funny letters:

**Output:** Here are some funny letters: English

```
$text =  iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $text);
```

the solution above can do this with some text styles but not all text styles.

Of course, we can decode each text style. What I want to know is if there is a simpler solution that can support decode all such playful text styles.